# quarto with vscode in windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, quarto

When render, an error pops: Quarto installation not found

But when I use quarto with cli: `quarto render myfile.qmd`, success

Environments:

os: windows 10 professional

`quarto --version`: 1.0.37

vscode Quarto extension: 1.29.0

`quarto check`:

```
[>] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.0.37
      Path: D:\Quarto\bin\
      CodePage: 936

[>] Checking basic markdown render....OK

[>] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.9.12 (Conda)
      Path: D:/miniconda3/python.exe
      Jupyter: 4.9.2
      Kernels: julia-1.7, python3, ir

[>] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK

[>] Checking R installation...........OK
      Version: 4.2.1
      Path: d:/R
      LibPaths:
        - E:/rpkg
        - D:/R/library
      rmarkdown: 2.14

[>] Checking Knitr engine render......OK
```

Path setting of Quarto extension in vscode: `D:/Quarto/bin/`

In ubuntu os, I can render successfully

Comment: This was an issue with quarto and has since been fixed, fyi see [this issue](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-vscode/issues/63)